# Subtract corresponding values from one associative array from another associative array; removing elements which have a zero value

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, integer-arithmetic, array-intersect

I have 2 associative arrays, like below.

```
Array
(
    [Turbine] => 0
    [Nuts and Bolts] => 6
    [Runner Blade] => 5
)
Array
(
    [Nuts and Bolts] => 10
    [Runner Blade] => 5
    [Turbine] => 1
)
```

What I want to do is compare the two arrays and return ones that have the same key but a different value. Similar to `array_intersect_assoc()`, but that returns all values that match which is not what I want. Using the examples above what I want to return is the difference between the 2 values, something like:

```
Array
(
    [Nuts and Bolts] => 4
    [Turbine] => 1
)
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v){
    $dif = abs($arr1[$k] - $arr2[$k]);
    if($dif) $newArr[$k] = $dif;
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: This works, however I get an undefined index error on the line `$dif = abs($linequants[$k] - $costquants[$k]);`

Comment: `if(isset($linequants[$k], $costquants[$k])){
    $dif = abs($linequants[$k] - $costquants[$k]);
    if($dif) $newArr[$k] = $dif;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$ar1;
$ar2;

foreach ($ar1 as $k => $v) {
    if (intval($ar2[$k]) != intval($v))
        $ar1[$k] = abs($v - $ar2[$k]);
    else
        unset($ar1[$k]);    // remove key with equal value
}
```

Comment: How could I change it to save the results into a new array instead of modifying the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
array_intersect_key($array1, $array2)
```

Comment: This doesn't test whether the values are different, and it doesn't subtract the values in the two arrays.

Comment: This just returns the values from the first array that are present in the other array, not the difference

Answer (score 0):

```
$diff = array_diff_assoc($arr1, $arr2);

$result = array();

foreach(array_keys($diff) as $key){
    $result[$key] = abs($arr1[$key] - $arr2[$key]);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind mutating the second array, then performing some conditional arithematic and unsetting will get the job done.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kieFb))

```
$new = [
    'Turbine' => 0,
    'Nuts and Bolts' => 6,
    'Runner Blade' => 5
];
$old = [
    'Nuts and Bolts' => 10,
    'Runner Blade' => 5,
    'Turbine' => 1
];

foreach ($old as $k => &$v) {
    if (empty($new[$k])) {
        continue;          // ignore if key not in $new array or is zero
    }
    $v -= $new[$k];        // subtract new value from old value
    if (!$v) {
        unset($old[$k]);   // if old value has become zero, unset it
    }
}
var_export($old);
```